# adobe flash is copying items instead of moving them

Tags: flash-cs5

My friend has been using abobe flash for a while now, and said normally when he clicks and drags an object on the screen it moves it.  Lately however, it's been copying the item he selects.  He is running Mountain Lion, and has rebooted many times, as well at check for stuck keys.  Has anyone else had this problem, and if so, have you resolved it?

Thanks.

Comment: we did find this, don't know if it will solve the problem: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3383843#3383843#3383843

Comment: we also tried installing CS-6, but it's still not working properly

Comment: Ok, I read more into the FAQ, I'll post questions like this in other (more relevant) parts of stack exchange next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! Issue is resolved, turns out this was an issue with the program Air Display - not sure sure if this is unique to Mountain Lion - but as soon as I uninstalled Air Display, everything worked as normal again!